# How to convert numbers to currency in echarts?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want to convert numbers to Turkish Lira currency in my charts that was built with echarts.js (v1) (https://ecomfe.github.io/). You can see my charts and echarts js codes below.

My chart:

[image: My Chart that was built with echart.js]

As you can see the example, the numbers are not readable quickly. So, i want to convert "49146729.18 TL" to "49.146.729,18 TL". (In Turkish, we use "." (dot) for separating thousand, use "," comma for separating decimal.)

Here is my echarts.js code:

```
// based on prepared DOM, initialize echarts instance
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('Cirolar'));

// specify chart configuration item and data
var option = {
    color: ['#ef6e6e'],
    tooltip: {
        formatter: '{c} TL',
    },
    grid: {
        width: '100%',
        left: '0%',
        top: '1%',
        bottom: '1%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: {
        data: ["2017", "2016", "2015"]
    },
    yAxis: {
        axisLine: {
            show: false
        },
        axisLabel: {
            show: false
        },
        axisTick: {
            show: false
        },
        splitLine: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Ciro',
        type: 'bar',
        // data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20]
        data: [{
                value: price2017.replace(/,/g, '.'),
                name: '2017'
            },
            {
                value: price2016.replace(/,/g, '.'),
                name: '2016'
            },
            {
                value: price2015.replace(/,/g, '.'),
                name: '2015'
            }

        ],
        label: {
            normal: {
                formatter: '{c} TL',
                show: true,
                position: 'inside'
            },
        }
    }]
};

// use configuration item and data specified to show chart
myChart.setOption(option);
```

**Update:** here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/johnvaldetine/wmxtLoyu/3/

Comment: link a codepen snippet

Comment: i updated my entry. you can see jsfiddle link here: https://jsfiddle.net/johnvaldetine/wmxtLoyu/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked your fiddle. Seems like the chart library offers a function formatter. So you could use it like this:

```
function format(data)
{
    data = parseFloat(data);
    return data.toLocaleString('tr-TR', {style: 'currency', currency: 'TRY'});
}

... //Inside the options
formatter: function (params) {
        var val = format(params.value);
    return val;
}
...
```

See this fiddle for a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lfrcbe9p/